# lua - how to authenticate to a HTTPS server?

Tags: authentication, https, lua, pushbullet

How would one authenticate and hit a HTTPS URL from LUA?   In particular to get the resultant response back from the server?

Background:  Basically want to use the https://docs.pushbullet.com/http/ API.  I can see how to use it in curl, however I want to use it within LUA, and really want to get the responses back to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LuaSec and LuaSocket. Require `ssl.https` and use it [like socket.http](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html).

Comment: Or you can use one of curl binding.